# Server is not working after zookeeper. I've created a log folder and mention its path still its not working

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

How to start this server?
Thanks in advance

I mentioned the logs in server.properties i followed many tutorials still kafka server is not starting. still it is not starting.

[image: kafka server not starting]

Comment: Windows is not a tested environment for running Kafka. Can you try a VM or Docker?

Comment: i tried VM but there are some issues. And many people used kafka on windows so i think it should work on windows as well.

Comment: "many people" outside of simple blog posts and actually in production?

Comment: i tried on Ubuntu and "unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout of 6000ms" this was the error while starting kafka server while zookeeper is already running. and kafka is automatically shut down.

Comment: Sounds like a config issue. I can verify personally ubuntu works great. Especially when installed via apt-get

Comment: Any  link from which you did the configurations ?

Comment: The official Apache or Confluent sites that explain the broker properties are straight forward to me and everyone else I work with. If you have Zookeeper issues, there's only one config that needs changed